# Show a div inside a hidden div

Tags: jquery, css, html, selector

I have two divs inside a div and I want to show only one at a time

```
<div class="songContent">
    <div id="song1"> song 1 </div>
    <div id="song2"> song 2</div>
</div>
```

And I am triggering the event from another element using this function: (passing the string as an argument to the function, ex: songId = song1 )

```
function showSong(songId){  
    $('.songContent div').hide();
    var sel = '#'+songId;
    $(sel).show()
    $( sel +' div').show()
    alert(sel);             //debugging
}
```

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks,

Comment: Please see my answer, you can just do it in one line using toggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function showSong(songId){  
    $('.songContent div').hide();
    $('div[id=' + songId + ']').show();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Something like this?

```
function showSong(songId){
    $('#'+songId).show().siblings().hide();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

provided you have only one displayed at a time during the start you can simply use toggle.

```
$('#show').click(function(){
       $('div[id^=song]','#songContent').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you build a selector string that looks like `#song1 div`, it won't find your `song1` div. You need something like `div#song1`.

Example:

```
function showSong(songId){  
    $('.songContent div').hide();
    var sel = '#'+songId;
    $( 'div' + sel).show()
}
```

But the by-id selector by itself (`sel`) should have worked as a selector.